# Breaking without else statement

Tags: java

Each item has a unique code.

Item also have name it doesn't have to be unique.

Everything I add a code, if the code doesn't exist it will ask the name.

If the code does exists, it  it will only print out the below statement and 'break';

```
System.out.println("Already exists");
```

But when I type the same item code again.

Not only it print out the statement, it also still ask me the name.
Here is my code

```
        String code = //scannerobject;
        for(Item item: items)
            if(item..getCode().equals(code))) {
                System.out.println("Already exists");
                break;
            }
        String itemName = //scannerobject
        item.add(new Item(code,itemName));
```

.getCode() is just return method from Item class

```
private String code;
public String getCode(){
   return code;
}
```

Can someone explain to me?
Thanks.

Comment: Note that your code would be clearer and simpler as `if (items.stream().anyMatch(item -> item.getCode().equals(code))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, before adding a new item you want to check if the code is fresh. So, you need to make sure the loop has been finished without break and all items code has been checked. For performance improvement, you may want to consider binary tree to check for used code in O(log n).

```
String code = //scannerobject;
boolean isFresh = true;
for(Item item: items) {
    if(item.getCode().equals(code))) {
        System.out.println("Already exists");
        isFresh = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(isFresh){
    String itemName = //scannerobject
    items.add(new Item(code,itemName));
} else {
    //maybe exit or continue to outer while
}
```

Comment: this will cause the same problem i guess

Comment: what if the third item had the same code ?? it will ask the itemName then two times?

Comment: No, because asking name is outside the loop.

Comment: sorry,i have not seen you removed the `{}`,correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the object has not been found with some condition once the loop terminates.

```
String code = //scannerobject;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
    if(items.get(i).getCode().equals(code))) {
        System.out.println("Already exists");
        break;
    }
}
if(i == items.size()) {
    String itemName = //scannerobject
    items.add(new Item(code, itemName));
}
```

Comment: Better answer than mine.

Comment: Thanks, @ScaryWombat for the encouraging words. Salute to such a good spirit!

Comment: @ratRedTears - If any of the items does not have a name, it should ask the name - right?

Comment: there is a bug i guess,it  will only check  one item and match code what will  happen if there is multiple item?

Comment: It only checks the first item and imports new item in the loop which is not correct

Comment: Because you are adding the new item inside the loop.

Comment: @AmirMB - I understood the requirement as, `If the item code does not exist, it should ask for the name`. I asked the question to the OP but he didn't respond. But I can see that he has accepted your answer which means your understanding is correct.

Comment: The answer by @AmirMB is absolutely correct. I've updated my answer to match the requirement based on understanding when OP accepted his answer. This is just an alternative way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

We need to check the flag and ask for the itemName outside the for loop so that every item is checked.

```
String code = //scannerobject;
    Boolean flag=true;
    for(Item item: items) {
        if(item..getCode().equals(code))) {
            System.out.println("Already exists");
            flag = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(flag){
    String itemName = //scannerobject
        item.setName(itemName);
    }
```

Comment: It's exactly the same as my answer. I just didn't use curly brackets for the loop because it only has one statement.

Comment: @AmirMB sorry i didn't checked your answer properly,my bad!!